# Парсер .json на PHP

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

Нужно распарсить данную ссылку [ссылочка](http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json)

Делал так:

```
  <?php

 $url = file_get_contents("http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json");

 $arr = json_decode($url,true); 
 foreach($arr as $item) {
   echo  $item[0] ."<br>"; 
 }  
?>
```

Но выводит только по 1 значению, подскажите как распарсить весь документ, в PHP начинающий - уже пол дня ищу - но ничего не подходит, может и у меня чота с руками)

Заранее спасибо!

---

Спасибо всем - сделал так:

```
<?php

 $url = file_get_contents("http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json");

 $content = json_decode($url,true); 
 //print_r($content);

  foreach($content as $key => $subarray) {

    if($key != 'eventSoon'){
        continue;
    }
        echo $key;
    echo '<table style="border:1px solid red; margin:10px auto;">'; 
    foreach($subarray as $item){
        echo $item;
    }
    echo '</table>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Документ парсится полностью. В этом легко убедиться, выведя его на страницу (`print_r($arr)` после `json_decode`). Возможно, этот вывод натолкнёт вас на причину того, что выводится не всё, что спарсилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json");

foreach (json_decode($content, true) as $eventrType => $events) {
    echo "<h1>Type: {$eventrType}</h1>";

    foreach ($events as $event) {
        echo "{$event}<br>";
    }
    // or 'echo implode('<br>', $events);'
}
```